# Insert time with to_date

Tags: sql, oracle, time, to-date

please, when I create a table in SQL/Oracle like:

```
CREATE TABLE Visite(
    id  NUMBER(5) PRIMARY KEY,
    dateVisite DATE,
    heureVisite DATE);
```

and insert a row as:

```
Insert into visite values (1, TO_DATE('2018-12-14','yyyy-mm-dd'),TO_DATE('2:5:1','hh24:mi:ss'));
```

When I select the result I found something like that:

```
ID  DATEVISI HEUREVIS
---------- -------- ---------- ------------- --------
 1   14/12/18  01/02/18
```

While I expected that:

```
ID  DATEVISI HEUREVIS
---------- -------- ---------- ------------- --------
 1   14/12/18  2:5:1
```

Please someone can explain for me why ? and how can I insert a date as hours:minute:second ?

Comment: You can't. Oracle has no data type that can only store time

Comment: In Oracle, you would do much better to change the table structure, to have only one column for date and time, perhaps call it `dateheure_visite` (avoid upper and lower case - Oracle is case insensitive). The column should store both the date and the time.

Comment: Not just in Oracle; in almost all cases it's best to store it as a combined type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @Kiran suggested, you may hold your date info in a `timestamp` type column and compute in desired format while showing :

```
create table visite( id  number primary key, dateVisite timestamp );
/    
insert into visite values(1,to_timestamp('14/12/2018 02:05:01','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));
/  
select id, to_char(dateVisite,'dd/mm/yyyy') dateVisite, to_char(dateVisite,'hh24:mi:ss') heureVisite from visite;
/
ID  DATEVISITE  HEUREVISITE
--  ----------  -----------
1   14/12/2018  02:05:01
```

Answer (score 2):

You are inserting a `DATE` (which always consists date and time value) to both columns.

`TO_DATE('2018-12-14','yyyy-mm-dd')` gives 2018-12-14 00:00:00

When you enter a DATE without date value, then Oracle take first day of current month for date, so `TO_DATE('2:5:1','hh24:mi:ss')` gives 2018-02-01 02:05:01

See [DATE Datatype](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#sthref116)

> The default date values are determined as follows:
>
> - The year is the current year, as returned by SYSDATE.
> - The month is the current month, as returned by SYSDATE.
> - The day is 01 (the first day of the month).
> - The hour, minute, and second are all 0.

You see `14/12/18` resp. `01/02/18` just because of your current session settings of `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` which seems to be `DD/MM/YY`